# How to select from more than one record of the same field in a JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of letters. And table with authors and recipients called "people". I want to run a SQL command that returns a table or row with the letter and BOTH its author and its recipient.

Here's what I tried so far. If I need a table with letters and the author name I can use:

```
SELECT date, type, description, firstName, lastName
FROM letters
INNER JOIN people ON letters.authorId=people.ROWID
```

This gives me a table like the following:

```
1866-12-08  request need of women and children, list of needed supplies, FREEDMEN'S BUREAU  A.M.L.  Crawford
1867-01-18  request destitution of women and children in state and efforts to help  M.H.    Cruikshank
```

If I need recipient I can change the last line to:

```
INNER JOIN people ON letters.recipientId=people.ROWID
```

I want both the author and recipient. But I cannot seem to select more than one of the same field in a JOIN.

I have tried using the following.

```
SELECT date, type, description, firstName, lastName, firstName, lastName
FROM letters
INNER JOIN people ON letters.authorId=people.ROWID
INNER JOIN people ON letters.recipient=people.ROWID
```

This leads to the error:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: ambiguous column name: firstName
At line 1:
SELECT date, type, description, firstName, lastName, firstName, lastName
FROM letters
INNER JOIN people ON letters.authorId=people.ROWID
INNER JOIN people ON letters.recipient=people.ROWID
```

Comment: I would suggest you need to make use of table and column aliases - it's good practice anyway and crucual for correctly referencing columns that exist in both joined tables.

Comment: The error is pretty clear isn't it? You have the same table twice, without distinction between the two. How do you expect sqlite to know which you want to select from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you JOIN to the same table more than once, as you do to show senders' and recipients' details, you must give the tables aliases.

```sql
FROM letters
INNER JOIN people senders ON letters.authorId=senders.ROWID
INNER JOIN people recips ON letters.recipient=recips.ROWID
```

Then you can mention columns from `senders` and `recips` in SELECT, WHERE, and other clauses as if those were separate tables.

```sql
SELECT letter.date, letter.type, letter.description, 
       sender.firstName, sender.lastName, 
       recip.firstName, recip.lastName 
       ...
```

**Pro tip** In queries with JOINs, always qualify each column you mention with the table name or alias. Say, for example, `letter.description` instead of just `description`. It makes your query much easier to understand for the next person. or even your future self.